# \path command problem in a text document

Tags: paths

I´m dealing with a problem with a TikZ graphic. I´ve done the graphic in a new document. Now, I want to include it in a text.  When I compile the code in a new document there´s no problem but.. when I copy the code in a text document I can´t compile it.

The problem is \path commands. If I delete them of the code, there is no problem but If I don´t. I can´t compile the document.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Sorry for the annoyances. I´m new in this website.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[spanish,a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\large

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20, text centered,minimum     height=3em];

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, -latex',shorten >=0pt];

\tikzstyle{hex}=[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20, text centered,minimum height=3em];

\matrix [column sep=10mm,row sep=15mm]
{
% row 1
& \node [block,text width=6cm] (update) {Update properties}; \
% row 2
&
\node [block,text width=7cm,minimum height=3em] (momentum) {Solve momentum equations};     \
% row 3
& \node [block,text width=11cm] (pressure) {Solve pressure correction (continuity)    equation.\\ Update pressure face mass flow rate}; \
% row 4
& \node [block,text width=10cm] (energy) {Solve energy, species, turbulence\\ and other   scalar equations}; \
% row 5
& \node [block, text width=5cm,rounded corners] (converge) {Converged?};
& \node [hex](hexx) {Stop}; \\
}; 

\tikzstyle{every path}=[line]
\path (update) -- (momentum);
\path (momentum) -- (pressure);
\path (pressure) -- (energy);
\path (energy)-- (converge);
\path (converge) -- node [above] {Yes}(hexx);
\path (converge.west)-- node [above] {No} ++(-4,0) |- (update.west);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Did you load the right packages and libraries? Without seeing the code it's very difficult to be of help...

Comment: The the full code, something we can copy'n'paste to our own editors and compile without having to add someting.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: If I compile this code there´s no problem. But.. If I copy this code to other LaTeX document (using the corresponding packages) I get  "! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }."

Comment: This is a problem with some of the `babel` modules. Are you perhaps using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` in the document where you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Spanish module for `babel` activates `>` as a shorthand character.

Use `csquotes` and add `es-noquotes` to the options for `babel`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-noquotes]{babel}
```

(see the documentation of `csquotes` for nesting quotations, if you really need them).

Otherwise, turn off the shorthand for the duration of the environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\shorthandoff{>} %%%% <--- turn off the > shorthand
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{block} = [
  rectangle, 
  draw=blue,
  thick,
  fill=blue!20,
  text centered,
  minimum height=3em
];
\tikzstyle{line} = [
  draw,
  thick,
  -latex',
  shorten >=0pt
];
\tikzstyle{hex} = [
  regular polygon,
  regular polygon sides=6,
  draw=blue,
  thick,
  fill=blue!20,
  text centered,minimum height=3em
];

\matrix [column sep=10mm,row sep=15mm] {
  % row 1
  & \node [block,text width=6cm] (update) {Update properties}; \\
  % row 2
  & \node [block,text width=7cm,minimum height=3em] (momentum) {Solve momentum equations}; \\

  % row 3
  & \node [block,text width=11cm] (pressure) {Solve pressure correction (continuity) equation.\\
           Update pressure face mass flow rate}; \\
  % row 4
  & \node [block,text width=10cm] (energy) {Solve energy, species, turbulence\\
           and other scalar equations}; \\
  % row 5
  & \node [block, text width=5cm,rounded corners] (converge) {Converged?};
  & \node [hex](hexx) {Stop}; \\
}; 
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line];
\path (update) -- (momentum);
\path (momentum) -- (pressure);
\path (pressure) -- (energy);
\path (energy)-- (converge);
\path (converge) -- node [above] {Yes}(hexx);
\path (converge.west)-- node [above] {No} ++(-4,0) |- (update.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]